# Add few days to minDate in datepicker

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker, mindate

How do I change this code

minDate: '2012/3/4'+'5D',

```
var dates = $( "#from, #to" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
    changeMonth: true,

    **minDate: '2012/3/4'+'5D',**

    onSelect: function() { 
       var d1=new Date($('#from').val());
       var d2=new Date($('#to').val());
       $('#quantity').val((Math.ceil((d2-d1)/86400000)));
   }
});
```

to min date be=>2012/3/9

tanks.

Comment: Since you required to add a specific date to some days, so why there is two date? Can you please explain?

Comment: I will add 5 days to mindate(2012/3/4)
To be converted to "2012/3/9"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: If it's actually hardcoded, just change it to `'2012/3/9'`.

Parse the date, add 5 days, and convert it to a string again:

```
var d = '2012/3/4';
var parts = d.split('/');
var date = new Date(+parts[0], +parts[1] - 1, +parts[2]);

date.setDate(date.getDate() + 5);

var result = date.getFullYear() + '/' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate();
```

[Here's a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/Zvyha/)

And here it is put in your code:

```
var d = '2012/3/4';
var parts = d.split('/');
var date = new Date(+parts[0], +parts[1] - 1, +parts[2]);

date.setDate(date.getDate() + 5);

var result = date.getFullYear() + '/' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate();

var dates = $( "#from, #to" ).datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
    changeMonth: true,
    minDate: result,
    onSelect: function() { 
       var d1=new Date($('#from').val());
       var d2=new Date($('#to').val());
       $('#quantity').val((Math.ceil((d2-d1)/86400000)));
    }
});
```

Comment: can you edit my code, And add your code to it?    tanks a lot